# Correct LED derating

Tags: led, derating

I am currently looking at the datasheet of a LED and have snipped out the passage of interest.

[image]
The question is how do I find out the intensity I can reach at a specific temperature/current by using the these curves?

Assuming I have an high ambient temperature of let´say 80°C, the current derating curve (current versus Temperature) would tell that I can´t drive the LED with more than approximately 8mA.

Looking at the Intensity versus current, I can see that at 8mA, I can expect about 0.4 of relative Intensity. Fine so far.

Now what about the relative intensity via temperature curve? Do I have to consider the effect described in this curve separately to the derating done so far? Means at 80°C, I only have 0.5 of relative intensity, so I had 0.4 before, so combining would lead to 0.4*0.5 = 0.2 of relative intensity at 80°C and 8mA.

That seems really low. Is the interpretation I have described correct or did I considere some effect(s) twice?

Comment: Compound the two, so 0.2.

Comment: Concur, efficiency is down to 50% at 80 degrees, and you are limited to 8mA instead of 20mA so, you will get 20% of the light you would get at 20mA 20 degrees C. That is not as bad as you might think as the human eye is very much non linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comments agree, the derating described is correct, that means:
When driving the LED savely at 80°C (with about 8mA of forward current), the relative intensity is down to about 0.4*0.5 = 0.2 (w.r.t. to the intensity at a forward current of 20mA)